# ASUS P7H55-M doesn't detect IDE optical drive

Tags: motherboard, pata

I have purchased a pre-overclocked Asus P7H55-M motherboard / Intel i3 540 combo. I am going to use one SATA HDD and one IDE DVD RW drive. The motherboard only has one IDE sockets and several SATA sockets.

The problem I am having is that the BIOS only detects the SATA HDD and completely ignores the optical drive.

I have tried the following set ups:

- Setting the optical drive to Master/Slave/CS
- Moving the SATA drive to socket 2 rather than 1
- changing the optical drive with a spare
- changing the IDE cable
- Changing what connector to use on the IDE cable
- I cannot see any option in the BIOS relating to IDE.

Any ideas?

Thanks

---EDIT 14/11/10 - 15:39 -- SOLUTION:

The IDE controller was disabled within the BIOS. The setting was under advanced > onboard peripherals - I missed that option when checking the BIOS. oops!

Thanks

Comment: -1 to question for placing the solution as out of bounds and continuing to pursue this by blaming your lack of forethought and ability to read on a misinterpretation of your question...if you wonder why read the buried comments on my solution

Comment: +1 for giving a set of things you tried already. And @aking1012 : saying that he could not **see** any option is not the same as saying there **isn't** one. He didn't place the solution as out of bounds: Somebody smarter than me could have pointed out where the options related to IDE were hiding.

Comment: true enough, but this requires having access to the particular bios that he's using...this whole thing is really a dead issue/disagreement on how things should be handled more than it is an IT question.

Answer (score 1):

Is it detected with no SATA drives connected at all?  First things first get it recognized.  Is there a hard disk pre-delay option in the BIOS? if so turn that up (OC boards might think they are waiting long enough when they are not, had that problem before).

Comment: Hi, It does detect the SATA drive, but not the IDE optical drive. Is it still worth looking for a pre-delay option?

Comment: yes.  in some instances pre-delay is universal, in others it's just for sata or ide.  either way the bios doesn't care if it's an HD or a CD/DVD.  they just call it hard-drive pre-delay.

Comment: Ah found the problem. It wasn't the predelay, but you got me to it! Thanks!

Comment: Bogus question....you specifically made turn IDE on in BIOS out of bounds with "I cannot see any option in the BIOS relating to IDE."

Comment: "I cannot see" != "there isn't". You clearly have never worked in IT support.

Comment: I have...I expect people that work in IT support to use this forum and to adequately READ BIOS screens before posting something that is obviously discouraging a line of reasoning

Comment: -1 to question for placing the solution as out of bounds

Comment: and continuing to pursue this by blaming your lack of forethought and ability to read on a misinterpretation of your question

Comment: Your reply was an unnecessary attack at my question, especially since I had thanked you for your assistance already. Missing an option in the BIOS due to a mistake does not make my question "bogus" - in fact it makes it more valid as it may stop the next person making a similar mistake. Bitching about not getting an answer point is just sad. Grow up.

Comment: sorry you can't down-vote me in return as you only have rep of 1

Comment: edit your question to remove placing that as out of bounds and all comments about cannot see!=isn't there/pertinent comments and i remove the -1 and all pertinent comments

Comment: @aking1012 : I'm rather not-active here but I am on some other stackoverflow sites. You come off as pretty agressive. Aaron is a new user and didn't do anything wrong. You could have pointed out to Aaron that he could edit his own question to correct his mistake before voting him down.

Comment: @Joris Meys First, true enough...I am aggressive.  It is easier to give "motivation" than it is to explain and it typically results in more results.  Second, down-voting does not really gain me anything as a rep of 1 cannot go down any further, so I wasn't being spiteful to someone's rep...just trying to encourage a proper question asking format or solution.  I would have behaved differently given a greater rep and this way, now that he has been equalized (which typically happens) he will gain 10 "free" rep points for correcting his question.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE controller was disabled within the BIOS. The setting was under advanced > onboard peripherals - I missed that option when checking the BIOS. oops!

Thanks

Comment: It's general good practice to put your answer as a community wiki when you answer your own question, to add it to the question as an edit or to add it in the comments under your question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add a power connection to the IDE drive.  Sometimes a case gets busy with cables and you don't notice one is unconnected.